# How to include regular expression in tn.read_until()?

Tags: python, regex, telnet, telnetlib

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
tn.read_until("abcd login: ") --> This is only to match a particular pattern
```

Can a generic pattern be included in `tn.read_until()` ?
Ex: prompt can be `"xyz login: " , "abcd login: "` etc

In regular expression, we use `re.match('(.*)login: ',prompt)` . But i don't think so, this works in `tn.read_until()` because the parameter it expects itself is a pattern. Is there any way to handle it ?

Comment: Have you tried [`expect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect) instead of `read_until`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Telnet.expect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect) accepts a list of regular expressions:

```
tn.expect([r"\w+ login: "])
```

Comment: Can both tn.expect() & tn.read_until() be used in one script ? tn.expect() not working for "Password: " and "user@abcd:>" , "user@xyz:>" prompts. Says as timeout.